# Total number of similar items which meet uniqueness criteria

Tags: python

I have a list, `rods` which is made up of tuples of `length`, and `position`.
`position` is always unique for a given `length`. I want to find the most frequent rod length, and then the total number of occurrences of all unique (by `position`) neighbouring rods (including the most frequent). Broken down:

- First I want to find the most frequent rod `length`.
- Then I want to include all other rods that have neighbouring `length` by some criterion (+-1 in this example), BUT ONLY IF THEY HAVE A UNIQUE POSITION - NOT ALREADY ACCOUNTED FOR (either by a 'most frequent' rod in the original group, or by a 'new rod' added to this group by fulfilling the neighbouring criteria).
- And find this new total frequency.

I am able to accomplish this in the following way, by sorting and using sets, but perhaps there is a better solution:

```
import itertools
#tuples of (length, position)
rods = [(18, 21), (17, 2), (15, 3), (14, 21), (14, 5), (13, 6), (13, 7),
        (13, 8), (13, 9), (13, 10), (13, 11), (13, 12), (13, 13), (13, 14),
        (13, 15), (13, 16), (13, 17), (13, 18), (13, 19), (13, 20), (13, 21),
        (13, 22), (13, 23), (13, 24), (13, 25), (13, 26), (12, 5), (12, 21),
        (12, 2)]

lengths = [length for length, position in rods]

#gives tuples of lengths and their frequencies:
length_freq = (sorted([(k,len(list(j))) for k,j in itertools.groupby(sorted(lengths))],
               key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=1))
best_length = length_freq[0][0]

#cumulative frequency of rods near best_length, with unique position:
tally = (len(set((best_length,v) for j,v in rods 
         if best_length - 1 <= j <=best_length + 1)))

print length_freq
#output:
#[(13, 21), (12, 3), (14, 2), (15, 1), (17, 1), (18, 1)]
print tally
#output:
#23
```

Note `23` is the correct answer for this test data. As both rods with `length= 14` are positioned at points also occupied by rods with `length=15` (positions `21`, and `5`). And there is also an overlap at `position=21` for `lengths 13 and 12`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think yours is a reasonable solution overall, if a bit over-compressed. My main suggestion would be to break it down a bit more. Also, instead of using `groupby` here, it's better to use a `Counter` if possible, or a `defaultdict` if not. `groupby` is for lazy operations on pre-sorted material; if it's not pre-sorted and you don't need it to be lazy, you probably shouldn't use it.

Since [Nolen Royalty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10230150/577088) provides a `defaultdict`-based solution, I'll use `Counter` here, but see below for a drop-in replacement. The result is an O(n) algorithm; since yours sorts, yours is O(n log n), so this is a slight improvement.

```
import collections

#tuples of (length, position)
rods = [(18, 21), (17, 2), (15, 3), (14, 21), (14, 5), (13, 6), (13, 7),
        (13, 8), (13, 9), (13, 10), (13, 11), (13, 12), (13, 13), (13, 14),
        (13, 15), (13, 16), (13, 17), (13, 18), (13, 19), (13, 20), (13, 21),
        (13, 22), (13, 23), (13, 24), (13, 25), (13, 26), (12, 5), (12, 21),
        (12, 2)]

lengths = (length for length, position in rods)
length_freq = collections.Counter(lengths)
((best_length, _),) = length_freq.most_common(1)
print best_length

#cumulative frequency of rods near best_length, with unique position:
rod_filter = ((l, p) for l, p in rods if best_length - 1 <= l <= best_length + 1)
tally = len(set((best_length, p) for l, p in rod_filter))

print length_freq
print tally
```

Since you can't use `Counter`, for completeness, here's an alternative. It's a drop-in replacement for these two lines:

```
length_freq = collections.Counter(lengths)
((best_length, _),) = length_freq.most_common(1)
```

Simply replace them with this:

```
length_freq = collections.defaultdict(int)
for l in lengths:
    length_freq[l] += 1
best_length = max(length_freq, key=length_freq.get)
```

Also note that my previous code had an error; it's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on 2.6 so unfortunetly I can't use Counter. But this looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty straightforward method that seems pretty reasonable to me:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> rods = [(18, 21), (17, 2), (15, 3), (14, 21), (14, 5), (13, 6), (13, 7),
...         (13, 8), (13, 9), (13, 10), (13, 11), (13, 12), (13, 13), (13, 14),
...         (13, 15), (13, 16), (13, 17), (13, 18), (13, 19), (13, 20), (13, 21),
...         (13, 22), (13, 23), (13, 24), (13, 25), (13, 26), (12, 5), (12, 21),
...         (12, 2)]
>>> neighbor_cutoff = 1
>>> length_to_count = defaultdict(int)
>>> neighbors_for_length = defaultdict(set)
>>> for rod in rods:
...     length_to_count[rod[0]] += 1
...     neighbors_for_length[rod[0]].add(rod[1])
...     for i in range(1, neighbor_cutoff+1):
...         neighbors_for_length[rod[0]-i].add(rod[1])
...         neighbors_for_length[rod[0]+i].add(rod[1])
... 
>>> sorted([(length, length_to_count[length]) for length in length_to_count], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
[(13, 21), (12, 3), (14, 2), (15, 1), (17, 1), (18, 1)]
>>> [(length, len(neighbors_for_length[length])) for length in neighbors_for_length]
[(11, 3), (12, 23), (13, 23), (14, 23), (15, 3), (16, 2), (17, 2), (18, 2), (19, 1)]
>>> sorted(_, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
[(12, 23), (13, 23), (14, 23), (11, 3), (15, 3), (16, 2), (17, 2), (18, 2), (19, 1)]
>>> neighbors_for_length
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {11: set([2, 5, 21]), 12: set([2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]), 
13: set([2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]), 
14: set([3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]),
15: set([3, 21, 5]), 16: set([2, 3]), 17: set([2, 21]), 18: set([2, 21]), 19: set([21])})
```

Comment: Thankyou, I'm struggling to follow this. Are all the elements in the final line apart from (13, 23) spurious? And what are the elements (11,3), and (19,1)? There are no rods with length 11 or 19.

Comment: @fraxel `neighbors_for_length` maps a length to a set of all rods with a unique position that are "neighbors" to that length(ie have a length that is either 1 less, equal to, or 1 greater than the length).  This means that because there are 3 different positioned rods of length 12, there are 3 "neighbors" to a rod of length 11 even if that rod doesn't exist.  I've added what neighbors_to_length looks like, perhaps that will make it more clear.